# Reference for l-adic Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

I don't know much at all about Lie algebras or representation theory, and I'm trying to read Ribet's `Review of Abelian l-adic Representations and Elliptic Curves'.

Is there a standard reference for $l$-adic Lie algebra stuff, or a general reference on lie algebras and representation theory which is more suited to learning about $l$-adic lie algebras?

Comment: I would recommend Serre's Lie Groups and Lie Algebras and then Bourbaki : Lie Groups Vol1.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $l$-adic Lie algebra, a Lie algebra over $Q_l$? Representation theory of $l$-adic groups is not understand by its Lie algebras, if you hope for an analogy with Harish Chandra modules, but via Heckealgebras.